# How to create and use a custom daily log file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

In Laravel I'm defining a custom log file in `/config/logger.php`:

```
'mycustomlog' => [
  'driver' => 'stack',
  'path' => storage_path('logs/mycustomlog.log'),
  'level' => 'info',
],
```

Here's my stack driver for context:

```
'stack' => [
  'driver' => 'stack',
  'channels' => ['daily', 'syslog'],
  'ignore_exceptions' => false,
],
```

and I'm calling it as follows:

`Log::channel('mycustomlog')->info($e);`

---

**What I expect to happen:**

A (daily) log file is created and the exception is logged. I.e `mycustomlog-2019-11-07.log`

**What actually happens:**

No log file is created, but the following error is logged to `laravel.log`:

```
[2019-11-07 10:25:31] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: channels at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:232)
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
'mycustomlog' => [
   'driver' => 'daily',
   'channels' => ['syslog'],
   'path' => storage_path('logs/mycustomlog.log'),
   'level' => 'info',
],
```

Comment: perhaps you don't want the 'stack' driver but the 'daily' driver?

Comment: @lagbox attention as the reason I chose 'stack' was because i need both the 'daily' driver and the 'syslog' driver

Comment: you saying you want to use the `stack` driver doesn't mean it is using the `stack` channel you have defined ... that is a channel named 'stack' that happens to use the 'stack' driver

Comment: nice catch @lagbox i've added the channels but still not getting the custom log file created. see my comment in mrhn's answer below.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `daily` driver deletes the logs after the amount of days set under the `days` key . To keep them forever, just set it to `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have channels in the config `logger.php` see [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/bfd4b1e92f7c6b4e6b74cfdde995a5afad648d96/config/logging.php#L39). The point of the stack driver is to report to multiple channels.

```
'mycustomlog' => [
    'driver' => 'stack',
    'channels' => ['daily'],
    'path' => storage_path('logs/mycustomlog.log'),
    'level' => 'info',
],
```

Comment: I added the 'channels' to the config, now I'm no longer recieving the error, but mycustomlog-2019-11-07.log is not being created, and my errors are being logged to laravel-2019-11-07.log instead. is this because i specify the 'daily' channel?

Comment: yes because the channel named 'daily' is configured to work that way ... you would need to create your own channel that uses the 'daily' driver and configure that

Comment: @lagbox perfect thank you. I will update my question with the solution.

Comment: can any one answer this question  ?  ::   
         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478010/how-to-customize-file-name-of-log-in-laravel-8-0

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want it to be in the stack you can have your config to point to the single driver like this

```
'mycustomlog' => [
  'driver' => 'single',
  'path' => storage_path('logs/mycustomlog.log'),
  'level' => 'info',
]
```

Then call it the same way you tried on your own.

```
Log::channel('mycustomlog')->info($e);
```