# Separate log files for each time a job is run laravel

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-8, jobs

I have a Laravel 8 application where I run my jobs against specific accounts. For each account, I need a separate log file in a format such as "logFileName_122323123_2021-01-01" (logFileName__) and so on.

Similar question [how to customize file name of log in Laravel 8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478010/how-to-customize-file-name-of-log-in-laravel-8-0)
but this does not help me create a new file each time I run the job.

I tried in my job constructor but since I'm calling the Log statically, it doesn't retain its value.

```
Config::set(['logging.channels.processPbsNormalCampaignJob.path' => storage_path('logs/processPbsNormalCampaignJob_'.$this->accountId.'_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log')]);
```

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from Laravel [v8.66.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#v8660-2021-10-21) you can create a log channel on the fly. You can check the [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/39273) as [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#on-demand-channels) as well

So Based on Docs you can do

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::build([
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/processPbsNormalCampaignJob_' . $this->accountId . '_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log'),
    ])->info('Your Log data here !!');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This seems to be a viable solution to the problem, but I'm using Laravel v8.58.0. So I'm assuming this won't work?

Comment: You can use latest version by running ```compoer update``` since its just a patch release and it won't break anything.

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite the build? I have two jobs running from a single command and the Log::build files does not overwrite the previous stream.

Comment: the issues has been fixed in https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/bc50a9b10097e66b59f0dfcabc6e100b8fedc760

Comment: can you run composer update and check if the issues still pesists

Comment: Have you tried that

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by ManojKiran Appathurai is correct but I had problem when I ran two jobs from the same command. The unexpected result was that the once I built the log, I couldn't rebuild it.

What I've done now is:

Create this helper function

```
public function initializeLogger($fileName, $channel)
    {
        $path = 'logs/'.$fileName.'.log';
        config(['logging.channels.googlelog.path' => storage_path($path)]);

        return Log::channel($channel);
    }
```

Then you can create a new channel name that's specific to a job such as

```
'importAccountEntitiesJob' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/importAccountEntitiesJob.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 0,
        ],
```

What all this is going to do is change the name of the channel dynamically. Now since we have different channels for each job, we can easily have separate logs for each job even if they're being run from a single command.